# character to date in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an excel which includes dates. I'm importing this excel file into a 'data frame'.
After importing, I tried to convert one column into an date format, but it's displaying 'NA'

What I tried:

```
str(df$Date_of_visit) # prints type before conversion

df$Date_of_visit # values in the column

df$Date_of_visit <- as.Date(df$Date_of_visit, origin = "1899-12-30", format="%m%d%y") #converting to date

str(df$Date_of_visit) # prints type after conversion

print(df$Date_of_visit) # values in the column
```

Output I got :

```
chr [1:4] "43503" "43319" "43473" "43473"

Date[1:4], format: NA NA NA NA

[1] NA NA NA NA
```

Can someone help me out? What is the mistake I'm doing here?

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Mouni.

Comment: Please put your code in a code block (three back quotes to open and three at the end to close)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to not specify `format=` argument in your `as.Date()`, and convert the characters to numeric before using `as.Date()`. Example:

```
dte <- c("43503","43319","43473","43473")

dte <- as.Date(as.numeric(dte), origin = "1899-12-30")
dte
#[1] "2019-02-07" "2018-08-07" "2019-01-08" "2019-01-08"

format(dte, "%m%d%Y")
#[1] "02072019" "08072018" "01082019" "01082019"
```

You can use `format()` to convert the Date objects to character of your choice of format. Note that `format()` gives you character object, not Date anymore.